# Settings in c++ with file .txt

Tags: c++

I would like to make a read and write file in c++. I would also like the information i write be a string. so then i can read that string from the file and see the value. Im gonna use this sort of like a settings file where the program can read your settings that you've used and apply them without having to reconfigure the program everytime. In small here's what i got:

```
    int main()
{
    std::string tortilla = "tacos";
    std::string godast = "pizza";
    std::ofstream MyFile;
    MyFile.open("1.txt");
    MyFile << tortilla;
    MyFile.close();
    std::ifstream ReadFile("1.txt");
    while (std::getline(ReadFile, tortilla))
```

As you see the code is not done yet by far but i just want to learn this element for now. Thank you in before.

EDIT: Here i want the output of reading "tortilla" to be tacos. So the string is intact troughout

Comment: this is not a learning platform. Search some tutorials first.

Comment: I cant seem to find any?

Comment: Enter "c++ tutorial" in a search engine of your choice.

Comment: there must be a library you can include for reading config or ini-files.
Then you can probably leave your code nearly like it is.
You just have to include the lib and change the last line to use that lib.
Sorry don't know the name of the lib.

Comment: without that lib you have to split the lines by white-space or tab and use the first array-value as key and the rest as value.

Comment: sorry I assumed you put it like this in one line: "tacos tortilla" or like this: "tacos = tortilla", then a lib like I wrote above would be useful.
If you put in each line only values you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

To output the content of tortilla add:

```
{
    std::cout << "tortilla is " << tortilla << std::endl;
}
```

And iostream must be included for std::cout. HTH.